# using P/Invoke to call wimm from C# and am unsure about function signatures

Tags: c#, pinvoke, winmm

I'm trying to call Windows Multimedia APIs (winmm.dll) from C# using P/Invoke.

The reason is that I'm trying to port some unmanaged C++ code which generates tones at varying frequencies and have had no luck with managed libraries and so am trying to directly reuse the C++ code which works very well already.

I started off by going to pinvoke.net and looking up the various function signatures and pasting in the provided DllImport lines from there.

What's confused me, though, is the apparent inconsistency of how things are mapped.

For example, the waveOutPrepareHeader function ([MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743868(v%3Dvs.85)), [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm/waveOutPrepareHeader.html)).  The second argument is a pointer to the WAVEHDR struct.  The pinvoke.net page makes sense to me in that this should be an IntPtr which points to a block of memory containing the struct.  I prepared this using GlobalAlloc with GMEM_FIXED and then Marshal.StructureToPtr to fill in the data.  I then pass the pointer returned from GlobalAlloc as an IntPtr into the function.

However, for other functions like waveOutOpen ([MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743866(v%3Dvs.85)), [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm/waveOutOpen.html)) and waveOutWrite ([MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743876(v%3Dvs.85)), [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm/waveOutWrite.html)), the pointers to structures are passed as a ref to a managed struct matching the unmanaged struct.

Why the difference?  How does it work when passing in a ref to a managed struct?  Is the P/Invoke layer just detecting this and doing the mapping internally?

I'm wondering because I'm getting access violations in some cases while the code is running and so am trying to go through the function calls with a fine tooth comb and this just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Well pinvoke.net is pretty hopeless. You can't use it as a reliable source. Best to understand the principles and do it yourself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so does it make sense for a function which takes a pointer to a struct to pass in a ref to a managed struct?  Or should that always be an IntPtr referring to unmanaged allocated memory?

Comment: ref param to struct is perfectly normal. You'll find countless examples with some research.

Comment: There is rarely a unique way to define p/invoke functions and structures. 1) use C/C++ definitions and headers first, they are the true reference, don't trust MSDN (although the documentation sometimes fills gaps), 2) just think binary layout from C/C++ definitions, understand what they mean, and 3) use .NET annotations that will help .NET match this binary layout. If you don't now C/C++, it will be much more difficult.

Comment: I'm very comfortable with C/C++, when looking over the APIs and seeing pointers to structs that led me to using IntPtr to memory allocated with GlobalAlloc and initialized with Marshal.StructureToPtr.  I guess my confusion was seeing inconsistency in pinvoke.net and the use of ref to managed struct.  I was curious if the interop services was detecting that and converting it.  I have it working now and I'm using IntPtr for those args and it seems to work.  I've looked around and haven't found a clear explanation of how the ref to struct param thing works but I guess it must be interop magic :)

Comment: Granted, the access violations, which prompted my deeper look at these calls turned out to be due to a callback param.  The waveOutOpen takes a callback delegate.  I defined it based on the MS docs and incorrectly used uint (DWORD) for the param args instead of IntPtr.  So when it would return audio buffers to be I was truncating the pointers and getting the access violation trying to then free memory with the bad pointers :)